# Can I use appium to test the launcher app ie without pushing it to the device

Tags: android, automation, appium, ui-automation

We are creating a custom launcher app on an android device that we need to test using appium.

I would like to write tests for an app that is already installed and running on the device under test ie without launching it as it is already launched.

ie I would like to skip the following step as the launcher app on our device is protected from tampering.
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/Users/katrinameadows/Desktop/MessagingUi-publish-04.11.01.apk");

thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can launch your app without pushing the apk every time to the device.

In Desired Capabilites, don't set **app** capability. Instead, install the app on the device manually only once. And set the app package and launch activity in the desire capabilities so that it will not install the app every time on the device. **Add below capabilities :**

```
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.packageName");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "ui.activity.SplashScreenActivity");
```

and **REMOVE below capability :**

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/Users/katrinameadows/Desktop/MessagingUi-publish-04.11.01.apk");
```

Mark this answer as accepted if this works so it will be helpful for others.